# Shift text in Power Point 2007 text box using VBA

Tags: vba, code-formatting, powerpoint

I need to shift the position of text in all textboxes (1 textbox per slide). The subtitles' first language is in white and there's English in yellow. Now I'd like yellow to be on top, white below. So first I'd like to select white, copy, erase, go to the end of yellow and paste (with line break between white/yellow). Can it be done?

Maybe some change to such script would help?

```
Sub RemoveWhiteText()

    Dim oSl As Slide
    Dim oSh As Shape


    With ActivePresentation

For Each oSl In .Slides
    For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
        With oSh
            If .HasTextFrame Then
                If .TextFrame.HasText Then
                    If TextRange.Font.Color = vbWhite Then
                        oSh.TextFrame.Text
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next
Next

    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will move the first run with font color white to the end of the text box. 
Try this:

`Sub MoveWhiteTextToEnd(oSh As Shape)
 With oSh
    With oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Runs(1)
        If .Font.Color.RGB = vbWhite Then
            .Cut
            oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.InsertAfter (vbCrLf)
            oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Length + 1).Paste
        End If
    End With
 End With
End Sub`

Update your code with this call:

`If .TextFrame.HasText Then
     Call MoveWhiteTextToEnd(oSh)
 End If`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It does a great job with 1 sentence lines, but with 2 lines of white text it cuts just the half of it. It seems to stop at some extra spaces.

Comment: It should work irrespective of the numbers of lines of text as long as it is a continuous block of the same formatting. Sounds like the formatting maybe different in the two lines of white.

Comment: I thought of the same. Yeah, once I selected white again and ran the macro it worked. Thanks :)